# how does the tensorflow c++ code SessionFactory::GetFactory choose which session to use?Direct or Grpc Session?

Tags: c++, session, tensorflow

In tensorflow c++ code, there are two session types,

**tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc 
tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_session.cc**

I can find the session was initialized by method

**Status NewSession(const SessionOptions& options, Session out_session)**

in
**/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/session.cc**,

the question is, I don't know when was the *session_factories filled with "DIRECT_SESSION" in the following code:

```
for (const auto& session_factory : *session_factories()) {
   if (session_factory.second->AcceptsOptions(options)) {
       VLOG(0) << "SessionFactory type " << session_factory.first
          << " accepts target: " << options.target;
  candidate_factories.push_back(session_factory);
} else {
  VLOG(0) << "SessionFactory type " << session_factory.first
          << " does not accept target: " << options.target;
}
```

}

**/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/session_factory.cc**,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `session_factories()` map is populated by calls to `SessionFactory::Register()`, which is implemented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7c689a2fd5204b3df82909ed91e1a240342f192f/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/session_factory.cc#L44), and called in the small classes [`DirectSessionRegistrar`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7c689a2fd5204b3df82909ed91e1a240342f192f/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc#L184) and [`GrpcSessionRegistrar`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7c689a2fd5204b3df82909ed91e1a240342f192f/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_session.cc#L407). Notice that there is exactly one instance of both `DirectSessionRegistrar` and `GrpcSessionRegistrar` defined as a `static` variable in their respective source files. This ensures that the factories are initialized at static initialization time, before the first call to `NewSession()`.

Comment: thanks so much!But why there was only DirectSession registered before the NewSession? Is it caused by the  bazel build deps only contain  direct_session?If so, how to debug a grpc session?Would you please give an example ?I'm using the [exmaple](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/cc/guide) to debug direct_session.

Comment: BTW,I want to debug the code with some IDE like xcode or vs?Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: The example in that tutorial does not include the gRPC session implementation when building the `cc_binary`. To enable it, add `"//tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc:grpc_session"` to the `deps` of the target. (I don't typically use an IDE to debug TensorFlow, although if you're running on Windows, Visual Studio works pretty well if you make a debug build.)